# useSelector state returns undefined (React-Redux)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I checked my actions, reducers by console logging the payload, and I'm getting the data from my api as expected, but when I want to use my state value using useSelector hook, I have an issue.

This is my Post component where I want to use my posts state which comes from postsReducer reducer. (down below)

[image]

```js
import React from "react";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";

function Post() {

    const posts = useSelector((state) => state.postsReducer);
    console.log(posts); //undefined

    return (
        <>
            This is a single post
        </>
    );
}
```

This is my App component where I dispatched my fetch action to get data from api. (down below)

[image]

Actions (down below)

[image]

Reducer. (down below)

[image]

All API calls are working fine.
Only the `useSelector` is giving me headache !

Comment: In the `useSelector` 's callback function, can you try `console.log(state.postsReducer)` ?

Comment: Did you wrap your component to the Provider (https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#using-hooks-in-a-react-redux-app)? Did your state really changed (because default state is undefined). You can use https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/redux-devtools/lmhkpmbekcpmknklioeibfkpmmfibljd to see state changes.

Comment: Can we see the root reducer's shape? What do you see when you inspect `useSelector(state => state)`?

Comment: @dev1ce it would be helpful if you post code instead of image .

Comment: @KiraLT yes I did wrap my component to the Provider !

Comment: @ThunderboltEngineer it gives me error = 'state' is not defined

Comment: @Chandan which particular code you want, because it is somewhat big !

Help anyone ! not working

Comment: @KiraLT This is my main index.js

`import { postsReducer } from "./reducers";

const store = createStore(postsReducer, compose(applyMiddleware(thunk)));

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
    </Provider>
, document.getElementById("root"));`

Comment: Please review the SO help center at StackOverflow.com/help. All code, data, error messages, et al must be typed in as text. Images are not bet readable on mobile devices. Moreso, pics of text cannot be posted into code editors or search engines, thus it complicates the process of anyone being able to efficiently lend assistance. It also increases the risk of volunteers adding their own typos into your code sample. Be sure, too, to always include a fully functioning, reproducible example demonstrating your issue. You can edit your post to avoid closure, or to reopen it if it becomes closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I resolved the issue, It is weird but I changed nothing, what I did, I created an index.js file inside my reducers folder for combining all the reducer files (I only had one in this case but still) and then exported that and it worked !

```
import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import { postsReducer } from "./posts";

const allReducers = combineReducers({postsReducer});

export default allReducers;
```

Answer (score 1):

In some cases, a misspelling also causes the same error. For instance, your reducer could be postReducer but you access it as postsReducer

```
const posts = useSelector((state) => state.postsReducer);
    console.log(posts); //undefined
```